# How to make the x-axis labels appear between ticks

Tags: stata

Consider the following toy example:

```
sysuse sp500, clear
keep in 1/5

graph twoway (connected close date),xlabel(14977(1)14983, labsize(vsmall) nogextend)
```

[image]

The produced graph has data points, ticks and `x-axis` labels on the same vertical line.

Instead, I would like the labels to appear in between the ticks. How can I do this?

Comment: I endorse @PearlySpencer's suggestion. Standard devices include labels without ticks, setting the tick length to zero and setting the tick line colour to none. These aren't identical necessarily/

Comment: @PearlySpencer and NickCox Thank you both! This is super useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
sysuse sp500, clear
keep in 1/5

graph twoway (connected close date), xtick(14977(2)14983, tlength(*1.5)) ///
xlabel(14977.5(2)14983.5, labsize(small) nogextend notick) xtitle("")
```

[image]

For full details see:

- [Stata tip 55: Better axis labeling for time points andtime intervals](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0030)